# Where to find Simulation models of Electrical Components?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, altium, pspice, model

i have been working on altium designer to make schematic, pcb and simulate the circuit. I have used some components like Varistor for which simulation model is not present in altium, i tried as much as i could to search it through the internet but could not found the solution.

Though i found out that i use Orcade as simulator, maybe there these simulation models or pspice models exist. But i am not sure.
So kindly help me, i don't know if this question follow this platform guidelines, but still..

Does Orcade support possibly much larger database for components pspice models?
Is there a source where i can get pspice/simulation model for altium??

Comment: Do you mean "Orcad"?

Comment: No, Altium, but now i have switched to Cadence-Orcade.

Comment: OK. I never heard of it. You could add a link in your question. You're missing a few capital letters on the brand names in your question.

Comment: Before i was using Altium designer https://www.altium.com/,   but i couldn't find any simulation model for varistor in the library, so i have switched to Orcad.

Answer (score 2):

All simulators allow the installation of 3rd party simulation models.

Look first at the manufacturers' websites for popular and newer components, under tabs like technical, support, models, design files, simulation or the like.

Unfortunately, the availability of spice models can be a bit patchy. Older and less well used devices can be hard to find. A general web search can sometimes throw up models from other places.

You might, as Peter Smith says below, have to roll your own.

Comment: There have been occasions where I needed to make my own models (particularly for things such as ferrites and chokes)